# How to update datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working in c# project, i need to update datagridview control after inserting a new record. When i am doing this, the gridview keeps its old values also, what should i do to show only updated records

Answer (score 2):

You need to show what the data source that you are binding to is.  If it doesn't have any update functionality (implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, for example), then the grid won't be able to tell when a value changed and update itself.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted a snippet of your code for us to analyze so my best guess would be that you are neglecting to re-bind the Data/Gridview after row insert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [ResetBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resetbindings.aspx) when the bound data source changes unless the data source implements the appropriate notifications to give an update notification to the grid.